# When Cauchy-Riemann equations hold, WHERE does it tell you $f$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

So I've been asked

'Is $f$ analytic anywhere? Everywhere? Justify your answer.'

My function is $f(z)=z^2-iz+iz^2$ which I've expressed as $f=u+iv$ so I can use Cauchy-Riemann equations to test to see whether or not $f$ is analytic.

I've shown the Cauchy-Riemann equations do indeed hold. I have

$$u_x=2x-2y=v_y \\ v_x=2x+2y+1=-u_y$$

... I don't understand how to determine if it's anywhere or everywhere... I believe it's everywhere, but how could I tell?

Comment: It didn't like your `&` symbol, which has a special meaning in MathJax.

Comment: Ah apologies, and thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Note that "The sole existence of partial derivatives satisfying the Cauchy–Riemann equations is not enough to ensure complex differentiability at that point. It is necessary that u and v be real differentiable, which is a stronger condition than the existence of the partial derivatives, but it is not necessary that these partial derivatives be continuous." (from wiki).

However, in your case Cauchy–Riemann equations hold for all $(x,y)$ and $u$ and $v$ are everywhere real differentiable, so $f$ is analytic everywhere.

In general, if it's satisfied at some point $(x,y)$ then $f$ is differentiable at this point.

Comment: +1 for the first two paragraphs.  But I disagree that C-R equation satisfied at one point is enough to show analytic in a neighborhood.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. Could you give me an elementary example of a function that is analytic at some point but not at another, and how this affects the C-R equations? I'm a second year maths student at degree level, and I think that as far as we're concerned, C-R will always be real differentiable. (i'm assuming that means that C-R have no imaginary parts, yes?)

Comment: @GEdgar thank you, I fixed it. You're right.

Comment: @Doug: consider $f = |z|^2$. At which points is it differentiable?

Comment: well that is equal to $x^2+y^2$... strangely enough, that's the question before the one asked here. I found it to be non-analytic, so surely nowhere?

Comment: That's not correct. Use C.-R.

Answer (score 0):

> **Proposition:** A function $f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ if and only if it is Frech'et differentiable at $z_0=(x_0,y_0)$  and the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.

This is true, as you see from the statement, at a pointwise level. You do not need to know differentiability of $u$ or $v$ anywhere else.

HOWEVER, remember that existence of partials is a strictly weaker claim that existence of the Frech'et derivative. One sufficient (and by no means necessary) condition for $f$ to be Frech'et differentiable is for partials to exist and be constinuous on a neighborhood of $z_0$.