# Finding all differentiable $f(z) = u(x) + iv(y)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ where $u(x),v(y)$ are real valued functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

> Finding all differentiable $f(z) = u(x) + iv(y)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ where $u(x),v(y)$ are real valued functions.

I’m not sure what to do. Would $f$ be differentiable simply if and only if both $u$ and $v$ were differentiable?

My thinking is that if the limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}
$$ 
exists then it would be equal to 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h} + i\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{v(y+h)-v(y)}{h}
$$ 
and therefore would exist if they existed. But that doesn’t seem quite right.

I also thought about using Cauchy-Riemann equations, but seeing that I’m trying to find ones that are differentiable rather than those that aren’t, I thought they wouldn’t be of much help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am adapting this from the derivation of the CR equations, assuming that $f(z) = f(x + iy) = u(x) + iv(y)$. The limits taken for the complex derivative need to exist when considered going to $0$ along both the real and imaginary axes, i.e.
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z + t) - f(z)}{t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z + it) - f(z)}{it}
$$
exists. Plugging in $f$ we get
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z + t) - f(z)}{t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x + t) - u(x)}{t} + i \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{v(y) - v(y)}{t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\ 
=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z + it) - f(z)}{it} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x) - u(x)}{it} + i \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{v(y + t) - v(y)}{it} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},
$$
so it seems like all of the complex differentiable functions in that form satisfy
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(y).
$$
The left-hand side depends solely on $x$ whereas the right-hand side depends solely on $y$, so they are actually constants, say they are both equal to $A \in \mathbb{R}$, say (a real constant since both $u(x)$ and $v(y)$ are real-valued functions). Then
$$u(x) = Ax + B,\qquad v(y) = Ay + C,$$
from which $f(z)$ in full-generality is
$$f(z = x+iy) = Ax + B + i(Ay + C) = Az + (B + iC).
$$

Comment: How do you prove that $u_x$ and $v_y$ are constants?

Comment: @user330477 it's because $u_{x}$ is a function purely of $x$ (or a constant), and likewise $v_{y}$ is a function purely of $y$ (or a constant); but as $u_{x} = v_{y}$, the only way for this to hold is if they are constant

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{C}$, so the partial derivatives exists everywhere.  By the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z \in \Bbb{C}$ if and only if

- \begin{aligned}(1a)\qquad &{\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}}={\frac {\partial v}{\partial y}}\\[6pt](1b)\qquad &{\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}}=-{\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}}\end{aligned} are satisfied at $z \in \Bbb{C}$, and
- $u$ and $v$ are real differentiable at $z \in \Bbb{C}$

Since $u$ and $v$ in this question are functions with single variables $x$ and $y$ respectively, $(1b)$ is always satisfied, and $(1a)$ becomes
$$u'(x) = v'(y).\tag{*}\label1$$
Integrate both sides of \eqref{1} with respect to $x$.
$$u(x) = xv'(y) + C$$
Integrate both sides of \eqref{1} with respect to $y$.
$$u(x)y = xv(y) + Cy \tag{#}\label2$$
When $x\ne0$ and $y \ne 0$, this gives $$\frac{u(x)-C}{x} = \frac{v(y)}{y} = k$$ for some $k \in \Bbb{C}$, so
\begin{cases}
u(x) &= kx + C \\
v(y) &= ky.
\end{cases}

Hence, we conclude that $f(z) = u(x) + iv(y) = kz + C$.

Comment: Satisfying the CR equations at a point does not imply complex differentiable at a point. You need to know that $u,v$ are continuously differentiable (or, to be more precise, continuous differentiability suffices when paired with the CR-equations to imply complex differentiability). The phrase "if and only if" ought not be in the answer as it currently stands.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I've edited my answer to include the right equivalent conditions, which is [*weaker* than continuously differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1269756/290189).

Comment: Downvote removed. Indeed, real differentiability will suffice.

Comment: Why did you assume that $\frac{u(x)-C}{x}=\frac{v(y)}{y}=k$?

Comment: @user330477 From the definition of a function, the 1st part only depends on $x$, the 2nd part only depends on $y$.

Comment: Then, the same result could be applied to $u_x=v_y$ rendering your calculations futile.

Comment: @user330477 I didn't "assume $\frac{u(x)-C}{x}=\frac{v(y)}{y}=k$" at the first place.  I deduced that from (#), and the deduction is elementary: you keep one independent variable fixed, and change another one, so that one side of your quoted equation would be unchanged, no matter how you change the other independent variable.

Comment: You only deduce that $\frac{u(x)-C}{x}=\frac{v(y)}{y}$ and not that they both equal to a constant $k$.

Comment: @user330477 When you put an equation with independent variables, it's important to look at their domains.  When I posted my answer two years ago, I strove to be the quickest one to give an answer, so I left out this tedious and technical gap as an exercise for mathematical mature readers.  I'm glad that you're trying to fill in this gap.  You may follow the logic of my previous comment to get to the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

> Would $f$ be differentiable simply if and only if both $u$ and $v$ were differentiable?

No. The functions $u$ and $v$ must also satisfy the CR equations.

The [Looman–Menchoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem) states that a continuous complex-valued function defined in an open set of the complex plane is holomorphic if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy–Riemann equations.

Now by setting
$$
u'(x)=v'(y)
$$
and since this is true for all $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R}$,
one has 
$$
u(x)=ax+b,\quad v(y)=ay+c,\quad a,b,c\in{\mathbb R}.
$$
Theses are the *only* possible candidates for $f$ being (complex) differentiable.

Such $f$ would be continuous for such $u$ and $v$, by the Looman-Menchoff theorem, $f$ is (complex) differentiable. So one has found *all* the $u$ and $v$ such that $f$ is (complex) differentiable.